# Saving and Retrieving Quill Data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, quill

I am planning to make a `discussion forum application` using ReactJs, React-Quill,Node and Mongodb.

And its obvious that the post contains **code snippet and images**

So I don't have any idea how to save the post. 
Either its saved on **specific file format or on the database**.

So it could be retreived on the `original format.`

Comment: What is exactly the problem you stumbled upon? I don't know how Quill returns data, but I see no problem saving your posts as mongo documents. If they are >16MB, use GridFS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getContents` to get a Delta object which is in JSON. 
It looks something like this:

```
{
  startLength: 0,
  endLength: 10,
  ops: [
    { text: 'Hello' },
    { text: 'Quill', { bold: true } }
  ]
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/83

More on Quill Delta: https://quilljs.com/docs/delta/